# create drawable from xml file

Tags: android, dictionary, layout, drawable

I am working with map and trying to create marker as Drawable object from my layout file.
I need my marker view to change depends on the the type of point, and hence i declared my first image as static and my second image as dynamic(Change dynamically),but it is not working.

My layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/marker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/marker" >
  </ImageView>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/category"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/category_for_children" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My code:

```
Resources res = getResources();
try {
  marker = Drawable.createFromXml(res, res.getXml(R.layout.marker_on_map));
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Drawable.createFromXml` is not for loading `Layouts` or `View` into drawable!!
see this sample of its usage:

http://spearhend.blogspot.com/2012/04/load-android-drawable-from-xml.html

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not optimal because the link might become dead. Would you mind updating your answer to sum up the solution you are providing?